# How to slideDown() input box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a button that adds an input box right under the previous input box. I want to add an animation, trying to make it more smooth instead of just popping there. I tried this so far but is does not work. A fiddle example would be awesome.

```
var counter = 0;
$('#addinput').click(function(){
    $('#inputs').append('<input class="search" style="margin-bottom:4px;" type="search" name="word' + counter++ + '"/>');
    $('.search').slideDown();
});
```

Comment: slideDown() requires the element to be hidden in the first place http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
<input type="text" />
<button id="addinput">Add Input</button>
</div>
<br />
<div id="inputs"></div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var counter = 0;
$('#addinput').click(function(){
    $('<input style="display:none" class="search" type="search" name="word' + counter++ + '"/><br /><br />').appendTo('#inputs').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Notice that `slideDown` effect in your case won't work because the content of the browser displays is updated as soon as the div is appended. So basically, you need to hide  that div first ( you can use either `display: none` or `hide()`) before actually append it.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jcz2e/)